# Is UC Browser support available in amp-html

Tags: amp-html

According to https://www.ampproject.org/support/faqs/supported-browsers

amp-html are not supporting **UC browser** do we have any polyfill or support available of it.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/support/faqs/supported-browsers) stated, as of now, AMP only supports the latest two versions of major browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari and Opera. However, you may file a [feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually AMP started supporting **UC browser**(around oct'17). [cramforce](https://github.com/cramforce)(owner of amphtml repository) said that

> We already support UC. Updated docs accordingly. In practice UC doesn't support automated testing and so support is more of a best effort thing.

See [Amp for UCBrowser](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11195) and [Development on AMP HTML](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/contributing/DEVELOPING.md#supported-browsers).